# Serilized file from Java and `sizeof` operator in C language (JNI) are unequal

Tags: java, c, macos, java-native-interface, osx-mavericks

I have a Java code which checks for the size of the object(in bytes) with the help of Java Native Interfaces. I pass the object to be determined for it's size as a parameter.
Here is my Java code.

Dog.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;



public class Dog implements Serializable {

    public static final int LEGS = 4;



    private double weight;
    private String breed;



    public void setWeight(double weight) { 

        this.weight = weight;
    }



    public void setBreed(String breed) {

        this.breed = breed;
    }



    public double getWeight() {

        return weight;
    }



    public String getBreed() {

        return breed;
    }
}
```

DogTester.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;



public class DogTester {

    public native double getDogSize(Object dog);



    static {

        System.loadLibrary("DogTester");
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog dog = new Dog();



        dog.setWeight(80.98);
        dog.setBreed("Doberman");



        DogTester tester = new DogTester();
        System.out.println("Dog object required "+tester.getDogSize(dog)+" bytes");



        try (FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("Dog.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream object = new ObjectOutputStream(file)) {

           object.writeObject(dog);
        } catch(IOException ioexception) {

            System.out.println("IOException occured");
            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this header file by my own instead of using the `javah`.

DogTester.h

```
#include <jni.h>


#ifndef _Included_DogTester
#define _Included_DogTester

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif



    JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_DogTester_getDogSize(jobject);



#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

DogTester.c

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "DogTester.h"



JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_DogTester_getDogSize(jobject obj) {

    printf("Size of object from C program = %zu bytes", sizeof obj);
    return sizeof obj;
}
```

I compiled the above `C` program, on my Macbook pro 64-bit machine as:

```
gcc -dynamiclib -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin DogTester.c -o libDogTester.dylib
```

It produced a file named `libDogTester.dylib`.

I compiled the `Java` program as:

```
javac DogTester.java
```

It produced `DogTester.class` and `Dog.class` both.

And ran the code as:

```
java -Djava.library.path=. DogTester
```

The output is as follows:

```
Adityas-MacBook-Pro:Java aditya$ java -Djava.library.path=. DogTester
Dog object required 8.0 bytes
Size of object from C program = 8 bytes
```

Which clearly means that the size of my `dog` object is 8 bytes..
But, on right clicking on the `Dog.ser` file, produced due to serializing the `dog` object, and checking the properties by right-clicking, it says that the file occupies `81 bytes`.

While my `Java` and `C` program both said that it occupies only `8 bytes`.

Now I have three questions..

## 1>

Is it so that an object, when serialized, occupies more space, even though the `.ser` file contains only the `serialized object`?

## 2>

If answer to 1st question is negative, than why do I see difference in the size given by the output and the `get info` section on right-clicking the `.ser` file?

## 3>

Why is it so, that even though `getDogSize()` method was called before `println()` method in `class DogTester`, the result was printed by `Java` program before the `C` programs `printf()` procedure?

## NOTE:

When I add a `\n` in the `printf("Size of object from C program = %zu bytes", sizeof obj)` procedure in my `C` program, like this:

```
printf("Size of object from C program = %zu bytes\n", sizeof obj);
```

the order of printing the result reverses and the new output is:

```
Adityas-MacBook-Pro:Java aditya$ java -Djava.library.path=. DogTester
Size of object from C program = 8 bytes  
Dog object required 8.0 bytes
```

Any help? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you need to condense and isolate your problem more. Most people aren't going to wade through 5 sources files and the novel you wrote

Comment: @BrandonYates There is no way I could do it. All the files are dependent on each other. Please help. I just have three small questions.

Comment: Did you really need to devote 25 lines of your post to show me the "bark" and "roar" function?

Comment: @BrandonYates Ok, i'll delete them

Comment: Object serialization does something completely different to `sizeof` and neither of them tell you how much memory the object is using are using.  The Object serialization record things like the class name, the name of the fields as well as a header.  `sizeof` tells you the size of the `jobject` *handle* which is the same size regardless of what it the actual object is.

Comment: Java's println is buffered whereas the C printf writes more directly to the console. This is why it can appear first.

Answer (score 3):

`jobject` is a `typedef` (synonym) for `void *`; it's a *pointer* to the object, not the object itself.  `sizeof obj` gives you the size of the pointer, not the size of the thing being pointed to.

**Edit**

> Why is it so, that even though getDogSize() method was called before println() method in class DogTester, the result was printed by Java program before the C programs printf() procedure?

Standard output in C is usually *line-buffered*; the output won't be written to the console until the buffer is full or until a newline is seen.  This is why you saw the change in behavior when you added the `\n` to the C output.

I won't pretend to understand how Java buffers output relative to C, *especially* when JNI is involved, but it's clear from the behavior that the Java output was being flushed before the C output.

**Edit<sup>2</sup>**

[Online C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **7.21.3 Files**
> ...
> 3 ...When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be
> transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
> encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host
> environment when a buffer is ﬁlled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or
> when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of
> characters from the host environment...
> 7 At program startup, three text streams are predeﬁned and need not be opened explicitly
> — *standard input* (for reading conventional input), *standard output* (for writing
> conventional output), and *standard error* (for writing diagnostic output). As initially
> opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard
> output streams are fully buffered **if and only if** the stream can be determined not to refer
> to an interactive device.

emphasis added.

Comment: I'll accept the answer as it seems convincing for the 3rd question. Can I get some link or reference that supports your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sloutions to the first two questions.

## 1>

In the serialized file, what you saved was the `dog` object itself.
But in the program, what you are trying to print out was the size of the `reference variable - dog` and not the size of the `dog` object.
Hence, the difference.

## 2>

Probably, NO. There is actually no difference. Read the **1st** answer carefully. It says the reason we see different results.

Answer (score 0):

Your sizeof operator is telling you the size of the **pointer**  to the dog object. Not the size of the object itself. THe object itself is certainly bigger than that. I'd guess it is something like

- 8 bytes object overhead
- 4 bytes for each int
- 8 bytes for each method
- 8 bytes for double
- x bytes for string

Add it up yourself to get an approximation of the size.

Comment: I answered my own question for the first two points, legally. I need answer for the third question.

Comment: Would it hold up to examination in court? How can we be so sure it was legal?

Comment: Yes, We are allowed to answer our own questions.